# How to Create and Insert a MergeField into a Word Document when Developing a AddIn Using VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in, mergefield

Now I can insert a text after the current cursor,using

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.Text = itm.Value;
```

I want to replace the text with a **MergeField**,but I don't know **how to create a MergeField object** using VSTO and **how to insert it into a document**.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you insert merge field

```
object objType = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField;
object objFieldName = fieldName;
Word.Field field = range.Fields.Add(range, ref objType, ref objFieldName, ref missing);
```

To replace the text you can either for String.Replace in C# or [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118.aspx) object from Word Object Model.

Answer (score -1):

You could also just add in after the Word.Field field = ....

field.Result.Text = "Whatever you want";